# Updating widget at midnight (12 AM) fails

Tags: java, android, date, alarmmanager

I have a Hijri calendar app with a widget. The date of the Hijri calendar should change at midnight using the AlarmManager. The problem is that in spite of using Alarm Manager to schedule the midnight update, the widget doesn't update exactly at 12 midnight. It will update somewhere between 12 and 1 AM.

Where am I going wrong?

Java:

```
private static PendingIntent service = null;
private static long UPDATES_CHECK_INTERVAL = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;


    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {

        schedule(context);
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }


    protected void schedule(Context context) {
        final AlarmManager m = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        final Calendar TIME = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date now = new Date();
        TIME.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        TIME.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        TIME.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        TIME.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        TIME.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        long firstTime = (TIME.getTimeInMillis()-now.getTime());

        final Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);

        if (service == null)
        {
            service = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        }

        m.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, firstTime, UPDATES_CHECK_INTERVAL, service);
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.app.Widget" android:label="Calendar" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
</receiver>
```

Comment: Why are you substracting in `TIME.getTimeInMillis()-now.getTime()`?

Comment: To get milliseconds to midnight from the current time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to change the code related to Calender and AlarmManager.

This calender represents the exact time of *next day's midnight*. and the AlarmManager will fire the intent at that time *each day*.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); 

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, service);
```

**Note:** I think you should add the above code in the `onEnabled()` method. [Here is a highlight of the AppWidgetProvider's related methods](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AppWidgetProvider).

Comment: This does change the time at 12, but when the widget is enabled, it displays nothing initially.

Comment: it displays 00 when the widget is instantiated and at midnight, it updates and displays the current date.

Comment: Where did you add this code? And where did you put the code that will update your widget's date?

Comment: I added this code on Update and onEnabled and the code that will update mywidget is onUpdate

Comment: If your update code is in `onUpdate()` then the Widget should be instantiated. However, the Alarm code should go in `onEnabled()` only. So, try removing it from `onUpdate()`. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: I finally got it to work using `alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), service);`. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What are you trying to do here? calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

Comment: @coolcool1994 I Initialized the Calendar instance with today's date. Now I'm trying to get to the next day, hence `DAY_OF_MONTH` is incremented by 1.

Comment: Can you provide the full code of "protected void schedule(Context context) " because your code doesn't update the widget